# Filtering column's collection

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, filtering, webix

In my Webix datatable one column fetches the data from the DataColletion. The problem is in the column's filtering: seems like it works with the original data (that contains the ID) and ignores the value of the data collection. How can I change this behavior and filter datatable by the collection's value?

Data:

```
var mycollection = new webix.DataCollection({  
  data:[{
    id: '12',
    value: 'CollItem 1'
  }]
});

var mydata = [{
  id: 1, 
  name: 'Item 1', 
  troublesomeColumn: '12' // id of the CollItem 1
}];
```

Config:

```
columns:[{
  id: 'troublesomeColumn',
  collection: mycollection,
  header:{
    content:"textFilter"
  }
}],
data:mydata
```

[Code snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/97f1f609). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters work with the dataset, not with the templates or values from the linked collections. Therefore, you need to [create a custom filtering rule](http://docs.webix.com/datatable__filtering.html#customfilteringrules) as described in the Webix Docs, i.e. define the needed pattern in the `compare`property of the filter:

```
  {
    content:"textFilter",
    compare:function(value, filter, obj){
      var colValue = mycollection.getItem(value).value;
      toFilter = colValue.toString().toLowerCase();                            
      filter = filter.toString().toLowerCase();
      return toFilter.indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    }
  }
```

[Updated snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/52f05a01)